# Disable alert e-mails from Mail / Calendar

Tags: macos, mail.app, calendar

I recently got a Macbook Pro for work, and am pretty new to the platform. One of the annoying things I noticed, is that after I configured all of my Gmail accounts, I started automatically getting these "alert" e-mails for calendar appointments.

I don't want Mail or Calendar to send me alert e-mails, because I already get them directly from Google.

My question is: How can I disable these alert e-mails from occurring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop email reminder from iCal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46024/how-do-i-stop-email-reminder-from-ical)

Answer (score 17):

It is indeed Mac Calendar problem as author of the question suggested.

I faced the same issue and observed that I get these nasty "*Alert - ...*" emails only when Mac wakes up. I also did not get them before I started using my Mac.

To solve the problem on macOS 10.12.3:

- Open Calendar app
- Find your Google calendar on the list and right mouse click it
- Select "**Get Info**" option from the context menu
- Mark "**Ignore alerts**" checkbox in the popup window (see screenshot).
  [image]

Comment: If only it was possible to selectively ignore them. E.g. display notifications but don't send emails.