# How do I get icloud to stop emailing me about my google calendar events?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, calendar, ical

iCloud, iCal and Mail integrates pretty well with Google Calendar, even though they are not both from Apple.

But I have a hassle when it comes to Calendar Notification in Mail App specifically.

I get notifications correctly on OS X, iPhone, about Google Calendar. But, my Mail.app keeps trying to send me emails about my notifications, so I either get duplicated emails (from both Google ou Apple) or, nowadays, I get hundreds of Draft in Mail since I've got 2 SMTP address from both accounts in Mail and it prompts me in each to decide which server show be default.

The thing is. I don't want either. **What I really wanted is that Mail could stop sending me mail alerts, but keeping Google Calendar and iCal/iOS calendar in sync.**

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop email reminder from iCal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46024/how-do-i-stop-email-reminder-from-ical)

Comment: I think it does (testing), but not sure if that will also remove all notifications, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Unfortunately it does. For this reason, I'm not using the accepted solution but one of the other workarounds: [create an email filter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233427/67191) to automatically delete these emails.

Comment: Right. That might be the easiest solution that would solve the problem, ultimately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go into your settings and turn off email alerts for your calendars. That should stop the emails, or if that doesn't , go to preferences in your email alerts and turn off calendar alerts.

Comment: Which settings? There's settings for icloud.com notifications, mail client, calendar client, mac os preferences has notification settings for all the apps already mentioned. Please specify as I've already searched all settings and options I can find.

Comment: this is not correct answer, due to "setting" to much. Please, can you clarify which?